# How to change the location of the column name in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Exercise 1: What are the minimum and maximum prices of each variety of wine? Create a Dataframe whose index is the variety category from the min and max thereof.

```
answ = pd.DataFrame()
answ['price_max_variety'] = reviews.groupby('variety').price.max()
answ['price_min_variety'] = reviews.groupby('variety').price.min()
answ.head()
```

Output:

|  | price_max_variety | price_min_variety |
| --- | --- | --- |
| variety | # this is my problem | # what is this row? |
| Abouriou | 75.0 | 15.0 |
| Agiorgitiko | 66.0 | 10.0 |
| Aglianico | 180.0 | 6.0 |
| Aidani | 27.0 | 27.0 |
| Airen | 10.0 | 8.0 |

I would like it to do it right. I have no idea how to make this look properly and because of the generic words can't find relevant information.

Comment: If you can't exert a minimum amount of effort to even copy the question from your exercise into text for us to look at, how can you expect someone to put forth effort on your behalf to do your homework for you?

Comment: @user3483203 This is no homework, I'm just trying to learn. I thought the image was more efficient I have no idea how to show you the output. And my question refers to something aesthetically of the output.

Answer (score 1):

The blank grey row that you've pointed out is there to make room for the name of the DataFrame's index, which is `variety`. That index came from the default behaviour of `df.groupby()`: the grouped-by column(s) end up in the index of the resulting DataFrame.

To override this, try `df.groupby('variety', as_index=False)`. Or, if you have a DataFrame with an index that you want to move into a column, run `df.reset_index()`.

Comment: df.groupby('variety', as_index=False) gave me the following :
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (707,2) into shape (707). However, df.reset_index('varierty') worked perfectly I never thought of reversing it back to a column to obtain the desired effect. thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome! That first error message probably occurred because you tried to assign the two-column result of the `groupby` to a single column of a DataFrame.